# Excel data cleaning

Tags: excel, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I'm looking for the best approach to clean and tidy Excel data for analysis and visualization. What I need is to get the data into format of one type of attribute, one column with a header on top of each column. You'll find an example of what I'm trying to achieve below. Afterwards I'd like to create a graphical overview using PowerBI.
Could I ask for tips?

**Sheet with data:**

Row 6-7 contains the first entity, row 8-9 the second etc.

[image: Sheet 1]

[image: Sheet 1]

**Problems with the sheet:**

- Each entity spans over two rows
- Top 4 rows are not relevant, fifth row contains headers
- Every approx. 50 rows there's a page break with empty cells

**An example of how I'd like to clean the data:**
[image: Sheet 1 cleaned]

Answer (score 1):

I have tackled this problem many times: You receive data from some old system which is formatted for printout on an character oriented printer.

When I only have to do it once, I carefully sort and filter the data using formulas to get the data from each second row right to the data in the first row. Then I eliminate the formulas, sort and filter and delete until I have got what I need.

When I have to do it on a regular basis, I write a VBA Script running over every line of the sheet, identify the relevant lines or data and copy them somewhere else (or delete the irrelevant ones, though deletion of lines in long sheets takes a lot of time).

If you want it more sophisticated you could read the data into some object structure and write out the object as Excel or XML or anything you like.

Any way, there is no simple solution. But if you know your data, you can find ways to identify the entities and put them into single lines.

The best way, of course, is to talk to the guy who creates the output and ask him or her for a decent CSV file.